# Receiving Flux SSE in Angular 5

Tags: spring, angular, flux, server-sent-events, eventsource

I have succesfully implemented this mechanism in my application:
https://vividcode.io/Spring-5-WebFlux-with-Server-Sent-Events/
I can receive events with curl every second, as shown in the example.

My problem is: I cannot receive these events in Angular 5. I have tried many things. Currently my service code looks like this:

```
public getMigrationProgress(processName: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('X-Authorization', this._sessionService.getAuthToken());
    headers = headers.append('accept', 'text/event-stream');

    let url = config.restApi.url + this.getResource() + '/' + processName;
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        let eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill(url, { headers: headers });
        eventSource.onmessage = (event => {
            observer.next(event);
            this.zone.run(() => {
                console.log('prpprpr');
            });
        });
        eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
            observer.next(event);
        };
        eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
            if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
                console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
                eventSource.close();
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

It only opens connection, does not receive events (Method onopen works once, onmessage - never). Server sends them though.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out that if you set event name on server, you cannot receive it by `onmessage` method.

In the example the event name was set to "random". In order to receive it you have to do it like this:

```
eventSource.addEventListener('random', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this, it was exactly my problem which took hours and hours of head banging as to why curl worked and Angular did not.